# What is the cardinality of 0..1 to * associations

Tags: database, cardinality

Suppose I have a UML diagram where there are 2 entities associated with each other through an association line.

```
--------                    --------
| E1   |- 0..1 -------- * --|  E2  |
--------                    --------
```

I know that there are 4 kinds of mapping cardinality. And they are:

1. One-to-one
2. Many-to-one
3. One-to-Many
4. Many-to-many

Here, E1 cannot be one-to-many because, I know that E1 has to be exactly one to be one-to-many.

But can it be many-to-many? Because it does not seem to have a "many" on the side of E1.

Comment: Doesn't this just imply an optional one-to-many association?

Comment: I actually do not know if there exists any "optional one-to-many association". Can you please provide any detail link to that? If there is any, maybe that would be the answer of my question.

Comment: I'm simply referring to a scenario where you might have a foreign key on the 'M' side of the relationship, which can accept `NULL` values. This would in essence be a '1:M` relationship where many entities are related to 0..1 entities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I think there are a few misconceptions that led you to this situation.

1. The answer to your question could vary depending on which model or diagram are you using, UML diagrams varies a lot between them
2. You are confusing RDBs mapping cardinality with UML multiplicity. There are similar, but not the same.

There are more than 4 in UML (not just the ones you mentioned), You can have 2..4 (unlikely, but possible) or whatever else you want.

3. Multiplicity works two ways on a relation, which it seems you know. Also is *normally* represented as `*..*` and not `*`
4. Is always important to keep the focus on the purpose of UML, which is to model. So put whatever you think will reflect the reality the best for the purpose of that diagram.

Hope it helps